# WPF 4.0 validation error

Tags: wpf, validation, datagrid

We recently upgraded our .NET 3.5 SP1 application to .NET 4.0 and noticed that validation appears to have been turned on (or reported) throughout all the controls e.g. a TextBox's Text property binded to a int property in the model would now gain a red border around it when a letter is entered.

In 3.5, writing a letter into it would not highly the text box with a red border and it would silently be ignored.

In 4.0, this is giving us problems in the DataGrid since it now changes the entire grid to read-only until the user fixes the error when it previously silently cleared the value.  If that row then gets deleted programatically, the entire grid would stay read-only.

Since we do not use the WPF validation framework, is there any way to restore the 3.5 behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you get this behavior because you have `ValidatesOnDataExceptions=True` in your bindings. Setting it to false or leaving blank should do the trick (AFAIK, it defaults to false).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  We don't have ValidatesOnDataExceptions=True or any code relating to WPF validation anywhere since we haven't been using that feature.  Setting it and/or ValidatesOnDataErrors to False doesn't seem to do anything either.  The red border remains.  This happens in a new project as well.

Comment: You're right. I just tested and I'm having the same problem. I would think this is a bug, because even when setting UpdateSourceExceptionFilter and returning null (which means that it shouldn't add any validation error), the TextBox thinks there is a validation error. I would suggest you to provide a custom converter instead